# log(1 + x)= x(1 + o(1))?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, logarithms, definition

What is the way to this transition?
$NM*log⁡(1-\frac{U}{L(θ)}$$+o(\frac{log⁡(NM)}{NM}$$))$=$(-\frac{U}{L(θ)}$$+o(log⁡(NM))(1+o(1))$

N=M→∞

x=$-\frac{U}{L(θ)}$$+o(\frac{log⁡(NM)}{NM}$)→0

I thought:
For |x|<1
:

$\frac{1}{1+x}=1−x+x^2−x^3+$…⟹Integrate both sides elementwise
$log(1+x)=x−\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}−\frac{x^4}{4}+…=x+O(x^2)=x(1+O(x))=x(1+o(1))$

But I'm not sure?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Some notes on the proper way of using MathJax. Instead of writing separate math expressions use a single one, instead of writing `$NM*log⁡(1-\frac{U}{L(θ)}$$+o(\frac{log⁡(NM)}{NM}$$))$=$(-\frac{U}{L(θ)}$$+o(log⁡(NM))(1+o(1))$` write simply `$NM*log⁡(1-\frac{U}{L(θ)}+o(\frac{log⁡(NM)}{NM}))=(-\frac{U}{L(θ)}+o(log⁡(NM))(1+o(1))$`. For common functions like log use `\log` so it renders like a single word. Use `\to` to get $\to$, `\theta` to get $\theta$ and `\infty` to get $\infty$

Comment: By definition, for any $k$, $o(x^k)=x^k\varepsilon(x)$ where $\varepsilon$ is a function and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\varepsilon(x)=0$$ so this is correct (assuming $\log$ is the neperian logarithm and not the decimal logarithm) : $$\log(1+x)=x+o(x)=x(1+o(1))$$

Comment: $\log(1 + x)= x(1 + o(1))$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=1,$ which is true because this limit is by definition $\log'(1).$